# nested: ScriptException [dynamic scripting disabled] elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, symfony

## How to enable dynamic scripting via symfony config?

> I have simply multiply 2*2 but it can't works.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/app/user/_search' -d '{
    "script_fields" : {
        "test1" : {
            "script" : "2 * 2"
        }
    }
}'
```

**File: config.yml**

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        app:
            types:
                user:
                    mappings:
                        name: ~
                        pin: {type: geo_point}                        
                    persistence:
                        # the driver can be orm, mongodb, phpcr or propel
                        # listener and finder are not supported by
                        # propel and should be removed
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\User
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
                        finder: ~
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add followings to your configuration:

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
```

For more information: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting

Comment: i have added this in elasticsearch.yml but till not working.

Comment: what is your elasticserch version?

Comment: elastic search 3.2.0

Comment: You mean 2.3.0? Have you restarted ES?

Comment: i use "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "3.2.0"